# Converting CStringW to CString resulting question mark

Tags: c++, unicode

My vc++ project's property "character set" is set to "Use Multi-Byte Character", I am converting CStringW (Chinese language string) into CString and it's converting the Chinese characters into question marks.

```
CStringA utf8;
int cc=0;
// get length (cc) of the new multibyte string excluding the \0 terminator first
if ((cc = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, stringw, -1, NULL, 0, 0, 0) - 1) > 0)
{ 
    // convert
    char *buf = utf8.GetBuffer(cc);
    if (buf) WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, stringw, -1, buf, cc, 0, 0);
        utf8.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Please help, I'm new in c++.

Comment: What are you doing with `utf8` after the conversion has finished?  Windows has no built in mechanisms to display UTF-8 strings.  Windows MBCS support is code-page based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion is working correctly, you can send the UTF-8 result to another program which requires UTF-8, or test it in a web browser, or test it in Notepad with UTF-8 encoding.

The only problem you may face is that Windows API cannot directly display UTF-8 string, so it may look as if it failed. For example, `::MessageBoxA(0, utf8, 0, 0)` will show the wrong result.

To see if the conversion worked, you can convert back to UTF-16. For example:

```
#include <atlstr.h>
...

CStringW utf16 = L"汉字 / 漢字";
CStringA utf8 = CW2A(utf16, CP_UTF8);
CStringW copy = CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);

if (copy == utf16)
    ::MessageBoxW(0, copy, L"success", 0);
else
    ::MessageBoxW(0, copy, L"failed", 0);
```

---

New Windows programs should be in Unicode (UTF-16). Note that Multi-byte and ANSI are deprecated.

---

To use Multi-Byte in an old program, set code page to `CP_ACP` or another language. For example, `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, ...)`. However this depends on codepage for the current thread and is not reliable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    //ANSI codepage for Greek language:
    int codepage = 1253;

    CStringW utf16 = L"ελληνική";
    CStringA ansi = CW2A(utf16, codepage);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(codepage);

    //This should appear correctly
    std::cout << ansi << "\n";

    //This won't show correctly in English language computer
    MessageBoxA(0, ansi, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Lastly, if project is not Unicode, and for some reason you cannot change it to Unicode, you still have access to Unicode API's (for example `MessageBoxW`) so you can patch the old program. For example, instead of using `CTooltipCtrl::AddTool`, use the equivalent WinAPI code which exposes Unicode functions:

```
CWnd *button = GetDlgItem(IDOK);
if (button)
{
    TOOLINFOW ti;
    memset(&ti, 0, sizeof(ti));
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(ti);
    ti.hwnd = ::GetParent(button->m_hWnd);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND;
    ti.uId = (UINT_PTR)button->m_hWnd;
    ti.lpszText = L"汉字 / 漢字";
    ToolTip->SendMessage(TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, (LPARAM)&ti);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are correct but how to display CStringW in "CToolTipListCtr", please suggest.

Comment: You don't work with UTF-8 in Windows, except when importing/exporting to internet etc. Windows uses UTF-16. Is your MFC project Unicode? Check Project Properties -> Character Set. "Character Set" should be "Unicode" or "Not set". What is it?

Comment: It is set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"

Comment: I forgot you mentioned that already in your question. You should change your project to Unicode. If you are working on an old project and it can't be changed, there are ways to get around it and change some of the functions to Unicode. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a simple function to convert `CStringW` to `CString`. This might help some people

```
CString CStrWToCStr(CStringW str) {
    //[ wide to multibite character conversion added by Mahedi Kamal
    LPCWSTR wideStrPtr = (LPCWSTR)str.GetBuffer();
    int requiredSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wideStrPtr, -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    char* multibiteStrPtr = new char[requiredSize];


    if (requiredSize > 0) {
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wideStrPtr, -1, multibiteStrPtr, requiredSize, nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    str.ReleaseBuffer();
    //]

    CString cStr(multibiteStrPtr);
    return cStr;
}
```